# Set up eclipse for Ext js and spket IDE plugin

Tags: eclipse, extjs

i need to set my eclipse for ext js.
I downloaded ext js 3 and installed spket plugin and did all the steps(setting javascript profiles) from this website.
http://ria.arunkumarm.com/2010/09/setting-up-eclipse-ide-for-extjs-jquery.html

But still dont see code complete.

Also i want to be able to run a very basic example on eclipse.
Any one know of any websites /tutorials that helps development in eclipse.I am looking for something like that explains everything from start.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use Eclipse menu ... help->"Install New Software".
You paste in the update site
 http://www.agpad.com/update/ 
then select Spket IDE when it appears and and follow the steps.

Thanks to http://forums.spket.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3667.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are here:

http://spket.com/extjs.html

NOTE: When you add the update site, you must install all the items (Spket, Xerces, and Spket text editor) or else it won't work.  Other than this small issue their instructions worked fine.